# React container: Can I nest html?

Tags: reactjs

I have a quick question about react.  If I have a react container, can I nest content inside of it?

For example:

```
<div id=“mount-node”>
  <p>I want this content to stay after the component mounts</p>
</div>
```

Is this possible? If so, should I be doing this?

Comment: Why don't you try and find out? (Spoiler: the answer is yes)

Comment: Do you have any code samples you could link me?

Comment: If you were to look at the react documentation (specifically the `ReactDOM.render()` method you would see that the answer to your question is no. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. Once you tell React to render to a div, react basically 'owns' that div. It will replace whatever is inside of it. If you want to pass something from outside React into it, this is possible, but you will want to do so with javascript. Remember when you render anything in React (including your top level component with `ReactDOM.render`), you can pass in props into your components as a means of passing data into them. So you can use props to pass the data you want React to include in your component's render.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the answer to your question is no. React replaces everything inside of the container node you pass in. Note the following quote from the React docs.

> `ReactDOM.render()` controls the contents of the container node you pass in. Any existing DOM elements inside are replaced when first called. Later calls use React’s DOM diffing algorithm for efficient updates.
>
> `ReactDOM.render()` does not modify the container node (only modifies the children of the container). In the future, it may be possible to insert a component to an existing DOM node without overwriting the existing children.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.render